# How do i append slide to particular div element?

Tags: jquery, slide, swiper.js

I want to append slide to particular div element, which slide has width and height not like than normal slides. I follow the steps they guided in their documentation. But, i can't set width and height not like than other slides.
My code is,

```
<div id="id_0" class="swiper-slide" onClick="add(0);">Slide 1</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>


var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
slidesPerView: 3,
slidesPerColumn: 2,
paginationClickable: true,
spaceBetween: 30
});
```

There, via `onclick` event, I get that `div` id and through this id, I get column value. Then I append my slide after last element which has that column value.

My append slide like this:

```
<div class="append-slide" style="width:200px;height:300px;">Slide 10</div>
```

How I do this ? I lost hours for this.

Comment: upload whats your try.

Comment: Can you post link to documentation which you are referring?

Comment: sure, this is, http://www.idangero.us/swiper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, with the steps below,

1) Via onClick event, get the id of div element which one clicked and also get its swiper column and row values.

```
s_row = $('#' + id).attr('data-swiper-row');
s_col = $('#' + id).attr('data-swiper-column');
```

2) Get & change the width of swiper-wrapper div, width is based on your append div width. Here my width is 420px.

```
wid = $('.swiper-wrapper').css('width') + 420;
$('.swiper-wrapper').css('width',wid);
```

3) Then, based on your swiper column get value, add margin left to next swiper column.

```
$('div[data-swiper-column=' + (s_col+1) + ']').css('margin-left', '420px');
```

4) Finally, append your div after the last swiper row of swiper column, which one get earlier on click.

```
$('div[data-swiper-column='+ s_col +'][data-swiper-row=7]').after('<div style="width:420px;height:200px;">Append slide 1</div>');
```

Notes: If any problems with swipe in after append new slide, please make sure you add swiper.init().